# Pyspark casting String to Integer always null

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, casting

I'm reading the following dataframe with pyspark

```
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+-------------------+--------------------+-----------------+
|              regiao|                  uf|                sexo|              faixa|           categoria|           qtCond|
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+-------------------+--------------------+-----------------+
|"Centro-...|"Distrit...|"Masculi...|"18 a 21"|"A-Condu...|      "100"|
|"Centro-...|"Distrit...|"Masculi...|"18 a 21"|"AB-Cond...|"10.137"|
|"Centro-...|"Distrit...|"Masculi...|"18 a 21"|"AC-Cond...|          "6"|
|"Centro-...|"Distrit...|"Masculi...|"18 a 21"|"AD-Cond...|        "25"|
|"Centro-...|"Distrit...|"Masculi...|"18 a 21"|"AE-Cond...|          "1"|
|"Centro-...|"Distrit...|"Masculi...|"18 a 21"|"B-Condu...|"15.419"|
|"Centro-...|"Distrit...|"Masculi...|"18 a 21"|"C-Condu...|          "7"|
|"Centro-...|"Distrit...|"Masculi...|"18 a 21"|"D-Condu...|          "6"|
|"Centro-...|"Distrit...|"Masculi...|"18 a 21"|"E-Condu...|          "1"|
|"Centro-...|"Distrit...|"Masculi...|"22 a 25"|"A-Condu...|      "457"|
|"Centro-...|"Distrit...|"Masculi...|"22 a 25"|"AB-Cond...|"24.148"|
|"Centro-...|"Distrit...|"Masculi...|"22 a 25"|"AC-Cond...|        "24"|
|"Centro-...|"Distrit...|"Masculi...|"22 a 25"|"AD-Cond...|  "1.126"|
|"Centro-...|"Distrit...|"Masculi...|"22 a 25"|"AE-Cond...|        "70"|
|"Centro-...|"Distrit...|"Masculi...|"22 a 25"|"B-Condu...|"33.386"|
|"Centro-...|"Distrit...|"Masculi...|"22 a 25"|"C-Condu...|        "18"|
|"Centro-...|"Distrit...|"Masculi...|"22 a 25"|"D-Condu...|      "407"|
|"Centro-...|"Distrit...|"Masculi...|"22 a 25"|"E-Condu...|        "24"|
|"Centro-...|"Distrit...|"Masculi...|"26 a 30"|"A-Condu...|      "996"|
|"Centro-...|"Distrit...|"Masculi...|"26 a 30"|"AB-Cond...|"40.192"|
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+-------------------+--------------------+-----------------+
```

I need to convert the last column to Integer to make some transformations, I am applying this code:
`newDF = df.withColumn("qtConds", trim(regexp_replace(col("qtCond"), "\"|\\.", "")).cast("int"))`

But It always returning `null` on conversion, I tried to apply the trim to avoid spaces but it not worked.

```
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+-------------------+--------------------+-----------------+-------+
|              regiao|                  uf|                sexo|              faixa|           categoria|           qtCond|qtConds|
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+-------------------+--------------------+-----------------+-------+
|"Centro-...|"Distrit...|"Masculi...|"18 a 21"|"A-Condu...|      "100"|   null|
|"Centro-...|"Distrit...|"Masculi...|"18 a 21"|"AB-Cond...|"10.137"|   null|
|"Centro-...|"Distrit...|"Masculi...|"18 a 21"|"AC-Cond...|          "6"|   null|
|"Centro-...|"Distrit...|"Masculi...|"18 a 21"|"AD-Cond...|        "25"|   null|
|"Centro-...|"Distrit...|"Masculi...|"18 a 21"|"AE-Cond...|          "1"|   null|
|"Centro-...|"Distrit...|"Masculi...|"18 a 21"|"B-Condu...|"15.419"|   null|
|"Centro-...|"Distrit...|"Masculi...|"18 a 21"|"C-Condu...|          "7"|   null|
|"Centro-...|"Distrit...|"Masculi...|"18 a 21"|"D-Condu...|          "6"|   null|
|"Centro-...|"Distrit...|"Masculi...|"18 a 21"|"E-Condu...|          "1"|   null|
|"Centro-...|"Distrit...|"Masculi...|"22 a 25"|"A-Condu...|      "457"|   null|
|"Centro-...|"Distrit...|"Masculi...|"22 a 25"|"AB-Cond...|"24.148"|   null|
|"Centro-...|"Distrit...|"Masculi...|"22 a 25"|"AC-Cond...|        "24"|   null|
|"Centro-...|"Distrit...|"Masculi...|"22 a 25"|"AD-Cond...|  "1.126"|   null|
|"Centro-...|"Distrit...|"Masculi...|"22 a 25"|"AE-Cond...|        "70"|   null|
|"Centro-...|"Distrit...|"Masculi...|"22 a 25"|"B-Condu...|"33.386"|   null|
|"Centro-...|"Distrit...|"Masculi...|"22 a 25"|"C-Condu...|        "18"|   null|
|"Centro-...|"Distrit...|"Masculi...|"22 a 25"|"D-Condu...|      "407"|   null|
|"Centro-...|"Distrit...|"Masculi...|"22 a 25"|"E-Condu...|        "24"|   null|
|"Centro-...|"Distrit...|"Masculi...|"26 a 30"|"A-Condu...|      "996"|   null|
|"Centro-...|"Distrit...|"Masculi...|"26 a 30"|"AB-Cond...|"40.192"|   null|
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+-------------------+--------------------+-----------------+-------+
```

Comment: I tried to change my read like this: `df = spark.read.option("header", True).option("ignoreLeadingWhiteSpace", True).option("ignoreTrailingWhiteSpace", True).schema(schema).csv(mypath)` and convert without the quote regex replace, but I got the same problem.

Comment: Ideally this should work:- 
df.withColumn("qtConds",col("qtCond").cast(IntegerType))

Comment: your code works fine with a sample of the values provided in the question

Comment: but it was not working, I don't know why, I checked the .csv files there are no special characters, and nothing like that, but still not working, if I change the schema to int or integer it not works, and If I try to cast using .cast(IntegerType) don't work again. I think I'm losing something silly here that I can't figure out what is it.